# Excluding rows from result set, LEFT JOIN and EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server

When you have two tables, and want to exclude rows from the second one, there are a multitude of options including EXISTS, NOT IN, LEFT JOIN and EXCEPT.

I've always used left join:

```
select N.ProductID from NewProducts N
    left join Products P on P.ProductID = N.ProductID
    where P.ProductID is null
```

Now I'm thinking it's cleaner to to use EXCEPT:

```
select ProductID from NewProducts
    except
select ProductID from Products
```

Are there performance issues of using EXCEPT?

Comment: Does your SSMS support Execution Plans and statistics?

Comment: Yes. But want to know from the experts on this.

Comment: Experts say "look at the execution plan" :)

Comment: lol. No they don't. Then they wouldn't be called experts.

Comment: Experts would help to interpret your execution plans but you haven't posted any. Upload them to a file hoster and post the links.

Comment: I think under the hood sql server will transform the except into an anti join anyway,but it`s better to check.There are too many variables to get an answer that is generally true.

Comment: Here's a great overview of your options: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Great article. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check execution plan and SQL profiler to choose the suitable query.

But, for me, NOT EXISTS is good. [Reference here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is all up to you, depending on how large the data.

You can use any of that (`EXISTS, NOT IN, LEFT JOIN and EXCEPT.`) depending on your requirement.

you said that you always use `LEFT JOIN` , and that is good.. because joining the two tables will minimize the execution time of the query, especially when you are holding large amount of data.

`JOIN` is advisable but it is always depends on you.

You can see the difference of execution time using the execution plan of sql.